# Changing Image in UIImageview having same tag

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview

I want to change image in UIImageview by renaming image name mechanism.

As i have lots of XIB in my project and i need to change backgroung image on click of button.basically user have theme-1 and theme-2 option.

on click of theme-1 i need to set bg_yellow.png on all imageview on all xib
on click of theme-2 i need to set bg_red.png on all imageview on all xib

this is possible by creating refrence of each imageview and writing if condition.But this is wastage of time and lots of effort.

is there anyway that i can rename my imagefile at run time under resource folder?

Comment: To achieve what you want, I would suggest using different bundles. And also before setting the theme, I would suggest to destroy the viewControllers, save the data in core data or sqlite maybe and then again reload the viewController XIBS and other images from for the other bundle and reload the data from core dat or sqlite db. In my opinion this will be the fastest way providing you with a generic code, such that tomorrow if u need to add another theme, u can just create another bundle and load that.

Comment: The best way is to subclass UIImageView. Create MyThemedImageView class with theme property. Changing this property must result in changing of image. You can change this property with notification, or you can create UIView subclass MyThemedView, so that it will automatically change theme of it's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

This line will change the `image` of all your `UIImageView`s:

```
[[UIImageView appearance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"]];
```

Run that line of code (with whichever image file you want) whenever you want to change your app's "theme", as you said.

**EDIT**

Per our discussion, here's an example of how you can set an image with the `tag` of `1`:

```
[(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"]];
```

Comment: but this code may change image on sub imageview?? as i have other imageview in same XIB.that i dont want to chnage only background one.

Comment: is there any option to change by tag as i can set same tag of all background imageview

Comment: FYI, you did say "all imageview on all xib". Do you mean by `tag`?

Comment: Yes my mistake i also have other imageview on same xib.but can i use tag?

Comment: You could use tags. You'd have to know what tags the image views have and hardcode the value into a loop though. You could also use an `IBOutletCollection`. Do you want to do either of these?

Comment: I can set same tag for each background imageview in XIB.as this is simple job.but can i use this code based on tag? something like

Comment: [[[UIImageView appearance] imageviewswithtag:5] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png]]

Comment: You could do it based off of the `tag`, but that code will have to run in every view controller, keep in mind. And that code is incorrect, `appearance` is used for setting app-wide values. Do you want me to post an example?

Comment: or is there anyway i can get the instance of all imageview using bg_yellow.png

Comment: Yes please. i dont want to write code in each view controller thats a bad job

Comment: You can't identify variables based on their `image`. I have updated my answer. However, to do what you're requesting you will have to have some code in each view controller file, there's no way around that. Unless you wanted to create a subclass which might be more of a pain for you.

Comment: [(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"]]; this line i have to write in each view controller is really a bad idea :(. But you really made me learn few things i will try that anyhow i can do with one line of code

Comment: You could put a modified version of it in a class method if you wanted, but yeah you'll have to call it in every view controller if you don't want to subclass or use `appearance`. Please accept my answer if it helped you. Good luck man!

Comment: also same thing i need to do for buttons and textfield do you have any other idea??

Comment: Pretty similar concept applies to those as well

Comment: i can not accept answer as it will misguide other becuase in my question i ask for i need to change backgroung image which mean only background image on view not other images

Comment: Wait, do you want to change the background color of all `UIView`s throughout your application?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60058/discussion-on-answer-by-rebello95-changing-image-in-uiimageview-having-same-tag).